# ontology with java(jena)

Tags: java, nlp, ontology, jena

I'm doing some project which is based on ontology.I want to identify semantic of the text that has entered by user.

Is there any possible way to fulfill my task dealing with ontology through jena?

Comment: probably yes, but you have to be more specific. what is your ontology, and what is the semantics you want to identify?

Comment: The ontology is covered on tourism domain.All the knowledge is stored in ontology.The application is developing using java."If the user ask question something like what are the beaches in somewhere?"I want to identify semantic of that kind of statement/text. 

Thank in advance!

Comment: You're looking for something like natural language processing or an expert system in Java?

Comment: yep..It is like a natural language processing!but I want to knw that is there any way to doing that kind of things using ontology quering with jena!

Thank you!

Comment: Simple answer: Jena is not a natural language processing system. The 'semantic' of 'Semantic Web' is not the same as, say, 'semantics' in natural language processing. That doesn't mean you can't write a natural language processor that emits data as RDF, but RDF (and, by extension, RDF tools like Jena) is neither necessary or sufficient for that.

Answer (score 1):

Jena doesn't do Natural Language Processing. You want to look at APIs like [Zemanta](http://www.zemanta.com/) or [OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com/), or tools like [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/).

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this:
http://nlp2rdf.org

The other answers are still correct: Jena is not NLP. But with `NLP2RDF` you can query NLP tool output with `Jena`.