# How to classify words to their correspoding categories?

Tags: java, nlp, classification, ontology, text-mining

I've to implement text classification for a long list of words. I've some categories defined e.g. If the word "UK" is in the list, it will come under "Regions". If the word is "Pizza", it will come under category "food".

How can I classify the words under different categories? Is there any open source tool available to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to classify the words in the lists for which you already have some categories defined, or documents containing a subset of the words?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The categories are fixed, but there can be any number of related/unrelated words in the words list.

Comment: I'm trying to classify words, after some pre-processing, i'll have a list of words. So I have to categories the words, not documents

Comment: But the words are already mapped to categories?

Comment: I've some categories defined. Now, for each specific word, I've to check that if the word is related to any category, if it is more or less related to that category, i'll put it in that categories bucket, otherwise i'll ignore it

Comment: Will wordnet help me in some way? or any other ontology repository? or some similarity algorithm? I'm confused!

Comment: Wordnet has a thesaurus, so you can use it to get related words. But, in practice I don't think this will help you. The usual way to do this is gather representative documents for each category and select the top N terms (by frequency, excluding stop words). So if you needed to identify words related to food then you could gather recipies & menus from the web (by crawling) and select the top N terms from these sites (excluding Stop words).

Comment: Ok, so I've to crawl the web and then feed the classifier for each category? I just found "Java WordNet::Similarity" at http://www.cogs.susx.ac.uk/users/drh21/. I think this may help and I will not need training data then.

Comment: Do you have a bunch of ontologies already, like OBOs?

Comment: No, I don't have any ontology, I want to know if it is possible using wordnet? Is there a source to find ontologies or I'll have to create my own? as explained by Joel?

Comment: Well, you just need a collection of representative documents. Crawling an appropriate website is one way of getting them. Good luck using  WordNet similarity - I think you'll find it's not precise enough for any practical application. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919095/ontology-with-javajena

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, text classification. you could query the dbpedia ontology, that has categories defined already for most of the words, from the wikipedia data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but if what you want is to build up a list representative words for a number of categories then you could do this by selecting the top N most frequent words, excluding [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words), from a set of documents representative of each category. This is an easy way of creating a very basic ontology.

For example, to create a set of words about **food** you could crawl the web for **[recipies](http://allrecipes.co.uk/) and [menus](http://www.just-eat.co.uk/)** and then select the most frequent words from these. I'd expect that once you have excluded stop words you'll have a good list of food related words.  For words related to **programming** you could crawl **stackoverflow.com**, etc etc...

Then again, this may not be what you're trying to do...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve. You have provided a very good way of doing that. Just a single point? Can similarity measure help us in this regard i.e. how much two words related to each other?

Comment: re: similarity - in theory yes, but in practice it's tricky and it's just much easier to generate word coverage by having large enough document sets for each class that you want to classify. You'd hope that by doing this you'll capture each and every common word in use relating to the category. Once you try it you'll see that the most frequent words are pretty representative.